# Will shared memory be released when the container is destroyed or stopped

Tags: docker, shared-memory

When I run a docker image with `ipc=host` and call `shmget` to allocate a shared memory in container, I can run `ipcs -m` to display this shared memory information on the host. And when the container stopped or removed, the shared memory is reserved, I must remove the shared memory manually.

So if a container run with `ipc=host`，the allocated shared memory by container will not be destroyed when the container stoped or removed.

But if I use the default ipc mode to run the docker image, I can not use `ipc -m` to show the shared memory information on the host.

Is there any method to know the shared memory is destroyed or not when container is destroyed or stopped. Or from the perspective of docker implementation, will shared memory be released when the container (do not run with `ipc=host`) is destroyed or stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. All resources allocated by docker will be released when it stop or removed. But for host mode, some resources belong to the host, container DO NOT release it.